Fill NA values in SpatialPixelsDataFrame: equivalent to terra::focal?
I try to fill NA cells in a SpatialPixelsDataFrame based on mean values from neighbouring cells. I wonder if there is any automatized approach equivalent to the focal function in terra (see here).
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(SpatialEco)

m <- raster::raster(ncol=20, nrow=20) # create raster
m[] <- runif(ncell(m))
m[m < 0.2] <- NA # simulate NAs
spdf <- as(m, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame") # transform to SpatialPixelsDataFrame


Funnily enough, you can use raster::focal(). Most of the function names from raster have been intuitively migrated to terra. However, some parameter names are not intuitive. For instance, NAonly = TRUE from raster is now na.policy = "only" in terra.
Here's how to achieve what you want using raster:
library(raster)
# Loading required package: sp

# Create sample RasterLayer
set.seed(1)
m <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20)
m[] <- runif(ncell(m))
m[m < 0.2] <- NA

plot(m, colNA = "black") # NA coloured black to illustrate


Now apply raster::focal() to fill NAs with mean of neighbours:
# Expand/pad the raster to accommodate edge NAs
m1 <- extend(m, c(1, 1))

# Fill NAs with mean of neighbours
m1 <- focal(m1, 
            w = matrix(1, 3, 3), 
            fun = mean, 
            NAonly = TRUE,
            na.rm = TRUE

# Crop padded cells to return original extent
m1 <- crop(m1, extent(m))

plot(m1, colNA = "black")


Then convert to SpatialPixelsDataFrame if required:
spdf <- as(m1, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")

